# Unity - input latency is way too high but game has decent frame rate

Tags: android, performance, unity-game-engine, optimization, input

I implemented input for my mobile game like so:
I have some buttons and I have anywhere else on the screen. 
Basically when the player touches the screen and not a button ingame, the character jumps. Now, It is implemented by using `OnPointerDown` and `OnPointerUp` that sets a `bool`:

```
public class JumpInput : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool JUMP;
    public void PointerDown()
    {
        JUMP = true;
    }
    public void PointerUp()
    {
        JUMP = false;
    }
}
```

If the player is jumping, it is checked by a `FixedUpdate` method:

```
if (!movementDisabled && grounded && JumpInput.JUMP)
{
    //then we can jump
    currentImageIndex = 0;
    animState = CharAnimStates.jumpStart;
    //added again from here

    //zeroing out the Y axis velocity if we had one
    rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(rb2d.velocity.x, 0.0f);

    //until here
    jump = true;
}
```

As I get decent frame rates even when using post-processing, I have no clue why the input is so delayed. I require assistance to verify if my solution for "anywhere on the screen input" is viable performancewise and it not, how to improve it.

Comment: Did you try using Update function, as it is called every frame, whereas FixedUpdate is called after a fixed time(default 0.02sec).
Also, you are changing the velocity directly rather using force, it may also affect. You can smoothen that out using Vector2.Lerp

Comment: I thought as it involves physics, it should be managed in the FidexUpdate. 
By the way issue was - as far as I could find out - that I used `multithreaded rendering` on a weak mobile device. After unchecking that and rebuilding the app, things have improved.

Comment: Oops, my bad, yes, shouldn't be doing physics things in update...